# Add an item to <ul> onClick when classes are the same

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a favourites feature (similar to the star on the left of this post here on StackOverflow) where when a user clicks on an element another element within that class will be added to a list, the main complication is that all the div's have the same class but different content.

So when you click on `.mydiv` the number from the respective span class should be added as a `<li>` to the `<ul>`. As an added bonus it would be great if the opposite was true too, ie clicking the div again removes the item from the `<ul>`

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv" > <span class="number">1</span> This is first div with same id. </div>
<div class="mydiv" > <span class="number">2</span> This is second div with same id. </div>
<div class="mydiv" > <span class="number">3</span> This is third div with same id. </div>
<ul id="favourites" > </ul>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('.mydiv').click(function() {
  $('#favourites').append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
});  ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uv25u/

**EDIT: I have just noticed that if two span's have the same number then you can not favourite them individually, ie. the script gets confused and thinks both divs are the same since they have the same span number, is there a solution to maintain this same functionality even when two span numbers are the same?**

eg. Can we get it to work if the HTML was this:

```
<div class="mydiv" > <span class="number">1</span> This is first div with same id. </div>
<div class="mydiv" > <span class="number">2</span> This is second div with same id. </div>
<div class="mydiv" > <span class="number">2</span> This is third div with same id. </div>
<ul id="favourites" > </ul>​
```

p.s. if the script also automatically added a new span to the added `<li>` which when clicked remove the `<li>` from the list that would be brilliant, is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: Also, please use `$('<li>').text($(this).text())` or you could have some unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uv25u/17/ <- compares on number
**edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/uv25u/20/ <- compares on entire content

```
$('.mydiv').click(function() {
    if (! $(this).hasClass('favorite')) { // if not already favorite
      $('#favourites').append($('<li>'+$(this).html()+'</li>'));  // add the cliked item to the favourites as an li
      $(this).addClass('favorite');  // mark clicked item as favourite
   } else { // if already favorite
      var content = $(this).html(); // store content of clicked div
      $(this).removeClass('favorite');  // unmark clicked item as favourite
      $('#favourites li').each(function() {  // loop trough favourites
          if ($(this).html() == content) { // check if contents match
              $(this).remove(); // remove from favourites if match
          }
      });

   }


});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter, I like you approach of adding a class since I am planning to implement a separate button which removes the item from the favourite list and adding/removing classes is probably the easiest way to do that. However I noticed that your script still suffers from the bug where if two span's have the same number then the script can not treat them separately. ie. if you add 2 div's with span number 2 both to your favourites and remove only one then the other is also removed since they have the same number. I explain this in the edit to my post above,is there a fix for this?

Comment: although i would strongly advice you to use some unique identifier for performance, you could just compare the entire content. Will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mydiv').click(function() {
    var number = $(".number", this).text(),
        $favourites = $("#favourites"),
        $li = $("[data-number=" + number + "]", $favourites);
    if ($li.length) {
        $li.remove();
    } else {
      $("<li>").text(number).attr("data-number", number).appendTo($favourites);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uv25u/16/).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing like below,

```
$('.mydiv').click(function() {
   var num = $(this).find('.number').text();
   var $fav = $('#favourites');
   var $fav_li = $fav.find('.' + num + '_li');

   if ($fav_li.length) {
      $fav_li.remove();
   } else {
      $('#favourites').append('<li class="' + num + '_li">' + num + '</li>');
   }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uv25u/7/

Comment: @Vega thanks for your help, I was implementing your code when I realised that if two span numbers are the same then the script would get confused and you would not be able to favourite them individually, can you take a look at my edit above and see if there is a fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mydiv').on('click', function() {
    var numb = $('.number', this).text(),
        elem = $('li', '#favourites').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() === numb;
        });
    if (elem.length) {
        elem.remove();
    }else{
        $("#favourites").append('<li>' + numb + '</li>');
    }
});  ​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yv3V/1/)